# Merge shapefiles to one tool not working?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, tools, data-management, mergeshapes

When using the data management tool "Merge shapefiles to one" in QGIS why is it copying one of my shapefiles instead of merging the two together as it should?

Comment: are all your shape-files of the same type, e.g. point-files?

Comment: They are both Esri Shapefile Polygons

Comment: I think it may be the coordinate systems. I'm still a bit unfamiliar with QGIS so I will have to play around with it for a bit. I will report back whether or not this resolves the problem in case anyone has a similar issue.

Comment: The coordinate system did not seem to be the problem. This tool is working for me with smaller data sets so it's possible that it is the size of the shapefiles that I'm trying to add together. I read that shapefiles can be up to 2GB and, together these shapefiles would only equal up to 71.9 MB.

Comment: Do the dBase files have the same attributes (field count, field names, and field types)?